# how to avoid black screen on change of intent in andengine?

Tags: andengine

I was working on game using andengine ,I'm struck with the loading screen.Each time when I press my menu items It takes some time to load the next activity, meanwhile a black screen appears,so can anyone please help me in setting a screen with loading text instead of getting black screen.

I have searched on it and came to know that while game starts a loading page or splash screen is set to load all the resources background to avoid black screen,so please suggest me any possible ways to avoid that issue.

Comment: Are you creating a new GameActivity each time?

Comment: Also for more reference you can use following tutorial series. www.matim-dev.com/tutorials.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to not break your application up into a set of activities as you would with a traditional android app. Instead, break your game up into a series of scenes.

Create a manager class to load and unload the scenes and textures for each scene.

As an added bonus, you will be able to animate the transition between menus and scenes. 
If you need a detailed breakdown of how to implement this, take a look at the book:
[AndEngine for Android Game Development Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/andengine-for-android-game-development-cookbook/book)

Creating a surface view, and loading the textures for that view are slow costly operations. Each time you create a base game activity, you are creating and destroying your entire SurfaceView and all of the textures. For the best user expereince, you will want to avoid this at all costs.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply,do you mean that I have to use scene manager concept by using single activity.

Comment: @ Plastic Sturgeon...I have created different activities for splash screen,level 1 and level 2 so this is causing the trouble of black screen as intents are passed in between.

Comment: @bindu - yes, that is what I'm saying. You will need to use the Scene as the primary building block for you game instead of the activity. Then write a manager to swap between scenes, instead of using intents.

Comment: The code samples from the AndEngine for Android Game Development Cookbook may be helpful. The book is also helpful.   http://www.packtpub.com/support/10411

Comment: hey I have many classes in my game so its not possible to implement the whole thing in single class so please suggest some other way.

Comment: You do not have to have it in a single class. You can make separate classes that extend Scene instead of Activity. Please look at the source code link I provided above. It will make things very clear to you.